# EPSG of "Albers equal area conic projection (WGS 1972)"

Tags: qgis, epsg

I am trying to work with a raster I found here:

http://geoplaza.vu.nl/data/dataset/continental-scale-quantification-of-landscape-values-using-social-media-data

The authors report the spatial reference system is  "Albers equal area conic projection (WGS 1972)". When I load it into to QGIS the CRS is not recognized. The proj4string is:

+proj=aea +lat_1=32.5 +lat_2=54.5 +lat_0=51.4 +lon_0=22.65 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS72 +towgs84=0,0,4.5,0,0,0.554,0.2263 +units=m +no_defs

Can anyone tell me what the EPSG of this CRS is?

Comment: There are no EPSG codes for all possible combinations of parameters. Your projection seems to be one of those. Define your own custom CRS https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html#sec-custom-projections.